# Гиперссылка в TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textview

Я в `TextView` добавил ссылку в виде *html*-тэга `<a href="google.com">Google</а>`. К `TexView` добавил атрибуты `android:autoLink="web"` и `android:linksClickable="true"`, но при нажатии на ссылку ничего не происходит. Может кто подскажет: "Что необходимо сделать, чтобы осуществлялся переход по ссылке?"

Comment: Добавьте к вашему textview в коде linkTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())

Comment: Можете всю конструкцию `<a href="google.com">Google</а>` заменить на `google.com`, если устроют ссылки в таком виде, и тогда клик будет работать.

Comment: Куда добавить код? После какой строки? Простите за глупые вопросы. Я еще новичок в этой сфере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*string.xml*

```
 <string name="link"><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></string>
```

*layout.xml*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:text="@string/link" />`
```

*Activity.java*

```
mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);
 if (mLink != null) {
   mLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
 }
```

Comment: A в активити после какой строки?

Comment: вставте в oncreate

Comment: В `OnCreate` что не получается. `mLink` вводится как ошибка

Comment: `TextView mLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link);` сделайте так

Comment: Думаю тут в `mLink`, `Link` является ID `TextView'a`?